# Issue with zlib while running makefile MacOS sierra

Tags: macos, homebrew, zlib

I am trying to run a make file in MacOS sierra, but it seems to have trouble with the header of the Zlib (see below).

I have tried to install a separate version with brew and pass the directory of the brew zlib installation in the configure file.

```sh
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/etherlab --with-xml-prefix=/usr/local/opt/libxml2 --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/opt/zlib CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
```

However, when I run `make` I got the error

```sh
$ make

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in proto
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in lib
Making all in LibDLS
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -I/usr/local/etherlab/include -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2 -std=c++11 -MT libdls_la-ZLib.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libdls_la-ZLib.Tpo -c -o libdls_la-ZLib.lo `test -f 'ZLib.cpp' || echo './'`ZLib.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/etherlab/include -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2 -std=c++11 -MT libdls_la-ZLib.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libdls_la-ZLib.Tpo -c ZLib.cpp  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/libdls_la-ZLib.o
ZLib.cpp:22:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<ZLib.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk
      [-Wnonportable-include-path]
#include <zlib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
         <ZLib.h>
In file included from ZLib.cpp:22:
./zlib.h:42:17: error: unknown type name 'string'; did you mean 'std::string'?
    EZLib(const string &pmsg) : Exception(pmsg) {};
                ^~~~~~
                std::string
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:194:65: note:
      'std::string' declared here
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > string;
                                                                ^
ZLib.cpp:90:5: error: unknown type name 'uLongf'
    uLongf out_size;
    ^
ZLib.cpp:104:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'uLongf'
    out_size = (uLongf) (src_size * 1.01 + 12 + 0.5);
                ^
ZLib.cpp:117:28: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Bytef'
    comp_ret = ::compress((Bytef *) _out_buf, &out_size,
                           ^
ZLib.cpp:117:35: error: expected expression
    comp_ret = ::compress((Bytef *) _out_buf, &out_size,
                                  ^
ZLib.cpp:118:34: error: unknown type name 'Bytef'
                          (const Bytef *) src, src_size);
                                 ^
ZLib.cpp:117:16: error: no member named 'compress' in the global namespace; did you mean simply 'compress'?
    comp_ret = ::compress((Bytef *) _out_buf, &out_size,
               ^~~~~~~~~~
               compress
ZLib.cpp:88:12: note: 'compress' declared here
void ZLib::compress(const char *src, unsigned int src_size)
           ^
ZLib.cpp:120:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Z_OK'
    if (comp_ret != Z_OK) // Fehler beim Komprimieren
                    ^
ZLib.cpp:123:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Z_BUF_ERROR'
        if (comp_ret == Z_BUF_ERROR) err << " (BUFFER ERROR)";
                        ^
ZLib.cpp:155:5: error: unknown type name 'uLongf'
    uLongf zlib_out_size = out_size;
    ^
ZLib.cpp:173:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Bytef'
    uncomp_ret = ::uncompress((Bytef *) _out_buf, &zlib_out_size,
                               ^
ZLib.cpp:173:39: error: expected expression
    uncomp_ret = ::uncompress((Bytef *) _out_buf, &zlib_out_size,
                                      ^
ZLib.cpp:174:38: error: unknown type name 'Bytef'
                              (const Bytef *) src, src_size);
                                     ^
ZLib.cpp:173:18: error: no member named 'uncompress' in the global namespace; did you mean simply 'uncompress'?
    uncomp_ret = ::uncompress((Bytef *) _out_buf, &zlib_out_size,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                 uncompress
ZLib.cpp:150:12: note: 'uncompress' declared here
void ZLib::uncompress(const char *src, unsigned int src_size,
           ^
ZLib.cpp:176:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Z_OK'
    if (uncomp_ret != Z_OK) // Fehler beim Dekomprimieren
                      ^
ZLib.cpp:179:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Z_BUF_ERROR'
        if (uncomp_ret == Z_BUF_ERROR) {
                          ^
1 warning and 16 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [libdls_la-ZLib.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Digging a bit more I found that I could try to add

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
```

to the header `zlib.h` but this does not work either.

What else can I do to solve this issue?.

Comment: This is a guess, but looking at the output I suspect that, when the program includes <zlib.h>, it wants the "standard" zlib.h (which is in /usr/include on MacOS), but because the MacOS file system is case independent, it gets ZLib.h instead, which is a completely different file (probably part of the package, given that there's a ZLib.cpp). I think my approach would be to chase down that ZLib.h, rename it to something else, and fix all includes to match. Having two different filenames that differ only in case is going to be a headache on MacOS...

Comment: Thx for your reply. I have found the `ZLib.h` and replace the `include <zlib.h>` for the complete path `include "/usr/local/opt/zlib/include/zlib.h"`. Which worked out for me. Thank you!